# how to access returned results from rowSet in Java

Tags: java, arrays, database, rowset

I'm trying to access what the rowSet variable has returned i.e. it is retreving everything from properties where two conditions are met, BUT:

```
        JdbcRowSetImpl rowSet = new JdbcRowSetImpl();
        int price = 300000;
        rowSet.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/litrealty");
        rowSet.setUsername("root");
        rowSet.setPassword("");
        rowSet.setCommand("SELECT * FROM properties WHERE city = ? AND price < ?");
        rowSet.setString(1, l);
        rowSet.setInt(2, price);

        rowSet.execute();
```

since this piece of code is retreving these informations from the database how can I access it and i.e. put into an array so I can scroll through it then via next/previous buttons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use while loop and iterate on your rowset and get the data

it would look something like this:

```
//Creating and Executing RowSet  
JdbcRowSet rowSet = RowSetProvider.newFactory().createJdbcRowSet();  
rowSet.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/litrealty");  
rowSet.setUsername("root");  
rowSet.setPassword("password");  

rowSet.setCommand("select Id, Name, Salary from employee");  
rowSet.execute();

while (rowSet.next()) {
    System.out.println("Id: " + rowSet.getString(1));  
    System.out.println("Name: " + rowSet.getString(2));  
    System.out.println("Salary: " + rowSet.getString(3));  
}
```

Instead i would suggest you to use **PreparedStatement** to fetch data base from database